# Android Annotations / Gradle / Android Studio build issues

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-annotations

I'm working on migrating a project to Android Studio/Gradle and I'm having some problems getting the project to build properly with Android Annotations. From the gradle console output it looks like the annotation processing is happening after compile? Is that right? Shouldn't it happen before? The strange thing is that if I hit run the "edit configuration" dialog appears with "Error: Default activity not found" at the bottom.

I have another project working with a very similar build.gradle file and it's running fine and I'm totally stumped on this one. Any help would be very appreciated!

Please note I've also tried various other methods including https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle but there's no difference in the result.

My build.gradle in the project root:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And build.gradle from my /android folder:

```
apply plugin: 'android'



ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '2.7.1';

configurations {
    apt
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
        exclude 'NOTICE'
    }
}




dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.0'

    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'

    apt "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"

    compile "com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.0"

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}


android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    aptOutput = file("${project.buildDir}/source/apt_generated/${variant.dirName}")
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
    println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
    println "****************************"

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
        variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
                '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
                '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
                '-s', aptOutput
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's my gradle console output:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :android:assembleDefaultFlavorDebug]

Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "aptOutput" on "com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@2b8bd36f", value: "/Users/marky/myapp...".
****************************
variant: defaultFlavorDebug
manifest:  /Users/marky/myapp Android/android/build/manifests/defaultFlavor/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
aptOutput:  /Users/marky/myapp Android/android/build/source/apt_generated/defaultFlavor/debug
****************************
Deprecated dynamic property "aptOutput" created in multiple locations.
****************************
variant: defaultFlavorRelease
manifest:  /Users/marky/myapp Android/android/build/manifests/defaultFlavor/release/AndroidManifest.xml
aptOutput:  /Users/marky/myapp Android/android/build/source/apt_generated/defaultFlavor/release
****************************
:android:clean UP-TO-DATE
:android:compileDefaultFlavorDebugNdk
:android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:preDefaultFlavorDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:preDefaultFlavorReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library
:android:prepareDefaultFlavorDebugDependencies
:android:compileDefaultFlavorDebugAidl
:android:compileDefaultFlavorDebugRenderscript
:android:generateDefaultFlavorDebugBuildConfig
:android:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugAssets
:android:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugResources
:android:processDefaultFlavorDebugManifest
:android:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources
:android:generateDefaultFlavorDebugSources
:android:compileDefaultFlavorDebugJava
*** compile doFirst defaultFlavorDebug
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/SLAudioPlayer.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/SLAudioPlayer.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SplashActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.SplashActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/SLAudioPlayer.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TabHostFragmentActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.TabHostFragmentActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/model/Chapter.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: package com.mycompany.sl
import com.mycompany.sl.SLPreferences_;
                        ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/Application.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DownloadListActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.download
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.download.DownloadListActivity_;
                                    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/api/SLRestClient.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TabHostFragmentActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.TabHostFragmentActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/Application.java:56: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: class com.mycompany.sl.Application
    public SLPreferences_ prefs;
           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/AudioPlayerActivity.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AddBookmarkActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.bookmark
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.bookmark.AddBookmarkActivity_;
                                    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/AudioPlayerActivity.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TranscriptActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript.TranscriptActivity_;
                                      ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/LoginActivity.java:35: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: package com.mycompany.sl
import com.mycompany.sl.SLPreferences_;
                        ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/LoginActivity.java:99: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: class com.mycompany.sl.ui.LoginActivity
    SLPreferences_ preference;
    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/ProductViewFragment.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VolumeActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.volume
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.volume.VolumeActivity_;
                                  ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/SettingsActivity.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: package com.mycompany.sl
import com.mycompany.sl.SLPreferences_;
                        ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/SettingsActivity.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DownloadListActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.download
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.download.DownloadListActivity_;
                                    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/SettingsActivity.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class FAQActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.faq
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.faq.FAQActivity_;
                               ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/nowplayingbaseclasses/NowPlayingActivity.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/SettingsActivity.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: class com.mycompany.sl.ui.SettingsActivity
    SLPreferences_ preference;
    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/nowplayingbaseclasses/NowPlayingButton.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/SettingsAdapter.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: package com.mycompany.sl
import com.mycompany.sl.SLPreferences_;
                        ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/SplashActivity.java:40: package TabHostFragmentActivity_ does not exist
    void launchMainActivity(TabHostFragmentActivity_.IntentBuilder_ builder){
                                                    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/StudyLogFragment.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StudyProgressProductAcitivty_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product.StudyProgressProductAcitivty_;
                                                 ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/StudyTimelineActivity.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StudyTimelineHeaderView_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory.StudyTimelineHeaderView_;
                                         ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/StudyTimelineActivity.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WeeklyHistoryItemView_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory.WeeklyHistoryItemView_;
                                         ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/nowplayingbaseclasses/NowPlayingListActivity.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/TabHostFragmentActivity.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: package com.mycompany.sl
import com.mycompany.sl.SLPreferences_;
                        ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/TabHostFragmentActivity.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BookmarkFragment_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.bookmark
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.bookmark.BookmarkFragment_;
                                    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/nowplayingbaseclasses/NowPlayingSherlockFragmentActivity.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/TabHostFragmentActivity.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: class com.mycompany.sl.ui.TabHostFragmentActivity
    SLPreferences_ preference;
    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/bookmark/BookmarkFragment.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/chapter/ChapterListFragment.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: package com.mycompany.sl
import com.mycompany.sl.SLPreferences_;
                        ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/chapter/ChapterListFragment.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/chapter/ChapterListFragment.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SLPreferences_
location: class com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter.ChapterListFragment
    SLPreferences_ preferences;
    ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/chapter/ChapterListItem.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TranscriptActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript.TranscriptActivity_;
                                      ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/studyprogress/StudyProgressActivity.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WeeklyHistoryItemView_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory.WeeklyHistoryItemView_;
                                         ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/studyprogress/chapter/StudyProgressChapterActivity.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AudioPlayerActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/studyprogress/chapter/StudyProgressChapterActivity.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StudyProgressProductItemView_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product.StudyProgressProductItemView_;
                                                 ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/studyprogress/chapter/StudyProgressChapterActivity.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StudyProgressVolumeItemView_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.volume
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.volume.StudyProgressVolumeItemView_;
                                                ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/studyprogress/product/StudyProgressProductAcitivty.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StudyProgressVolumeActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.volume
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.volume.StudyProgressVolumeActivity_;
                                                ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/studyprogress/volume/StudyProgressVolumeActivity.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StudyProgressChapterActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.chapter
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.chapter.StudyProgressChapterActivity_;
                                                 ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/studyprogress/volume/StudyProgressVolumeActivity.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StudyProgressProductItemView_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product.StudyProgressProductItemView_;
                                                 ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/videoproduct/VideoProductFragment.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VideoContentActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.VideoContentActivity_;
                           ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/volume/VolumeActivity.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PDFProductFragment_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.pdf
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.pdf.PDFProductFragment_;
                               ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/volume/VolumeActivity.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VideoProductFragment_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.videoproduct
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.videoproduct.VideoProductFragment_;
                                        ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/volume/VolumeFragment.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ChapterActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter.ChapterActivity_;
                                   ^
/Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/ui/volume/VolumeItemView.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ChapterActivity_
location: package com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter
import com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter.ChapterActivity_;
                                   ^
Note: Starting AndroidAnnotations annotation processing
Note: AndroidManifest.xml file found: /Users/marky/myapp Android/android/build/manifests/defaultFlavor/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
Note: Number of files generated by AndroidAnnotations: 74
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.util.SLUtils_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.videoproduct.VideoProductFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.videoproduct.VideoProductItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.videoproduct.VideoProductListAdapter_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter.ChapterActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter.ChapterListAdapter_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter.ChapterListFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.chapter.ChapterListItem_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product.StudyProgressProductAcitivty_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.product.StudyProgressProductItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.SLPreferences_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.Application_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.nowplayingbaseclasses.NowPlayingButton_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.nowplayingbaseclasses.NowPlayingListFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.nowplayingbaseclasses.NowPlayingSherlockFragmentActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studylog.SLNumberPicker_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studylog.StudyTargetPicker_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.chapter.StudyProgressChapterActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.chapter.StudyProgressChapterItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.model.SubProduct_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.model.Volume_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.faq.FAQActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.faq.FAQGroupItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.faq.FAQItemActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.faq.FAQItemItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory.StudyTimelineHeaderView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory.WeeklyHistoryDayView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory.WeeklyHistoryItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.weeklyhistory.WeeklyHistoryView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.volume.VolumeActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.volume.VolumeAdapter_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.volume.VolumeFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.volume.VolumeItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript.TranscriptActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript.TranscriptCaptionItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript.TranscriptCharacterItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript.TranscriptHeaderView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.transcript.TranscriptNarrationItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.pdf.PDFItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.pdf.PDFProductAdapter_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.pdf.PDFProductFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.AudioPlayerActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.LoginActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.LozengeTabIndicator_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.PhoneProductFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.PhoneProductHeaderView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.PlayerFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.ProductFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.ProductTabFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.ProductViewFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.SLTabView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.SettingsActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.SettingsAdapter_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.SplashActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.StudyLogFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.StudyTargetActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.StudyTimelineActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.TabHostFragmentActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.VideoContentActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.VideoPlayerActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.VolumeTitleView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.StudyProgressActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.api.SLAuthInterceptor_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.api.SLAuthStore_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.api.SLRestClient_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.volume.StudyProgressVolumeActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.studyprogress.volume.StudyProgressVolumeItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.bookmark.AddBookmarkActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.bookmark.BookmarkFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.bookmark.BookmarkItemView_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.download.DownloadListActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.download.DownloadListItemProduct_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.download.DownloadVideoListItem_
Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.sl.ui.download.DownloadedVolumeListItem_
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 837 ms], [Generate Sources = 590 ms], [Validate Annotations = 84 ms], [Process Annotations = 84 ms], [Extract Annotations = 41 ms], [Find R Classes = 27 ms], [Extract Manifest = 11 ms], 
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 0 ms], 
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 0 ms], 
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[androidManifestFile]'
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/marky/myapp Android/android/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sl/api/SLRestClient.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:android:preDexDefaultFlavorDebug
:android:dexDefaultFlavorDebug
:android:processDefaultFlavorDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:android:validateDebugSigning
:android:packageDefaultFlavorDebug
:android:assembleDefaultFlavorDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 56.231 secs
```

Comment: open you AndroidManifest.xml file and make sure the Main launcher activity definition in manifest is not complaining an error. It happened with me days back and the problem was the manifest.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I checked the AndroidManifest.xml and it's fine. It was also running fine with exactly the same AndroidManifest.xml in Eclipse so I don't think it's that.

Comment: @Marky Did you find any solution to your issue ?

Comment: Not yet I'm afraid. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. My build.gradle is very similar too.  I'm using Android Studio 0.5.8 and Gradle 1.10.  Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the apt plugin in your global build.gradle, you didn't apply it in your module's build.gradle and you didn't configure it. As Android Annotations works with the Android Annotation Processor, it needs to know where the generated sources are. The correct setup would be:

The global build.gradle code snippet:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        // small Gradle plugin that helps out when using an annotation processor
        // --> Android Annotations
        // makes the build code "available" to android studio
        // adds it to the source path
        classpath "com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4"
    } 
}
```

The module's one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

configurations {
    apt
}

// Configure the annotation processor and tell it where the manifest and the generated sources are.
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "de.company.android.app"
    }
}
```

In addition to that you shouldn't use the googlecode-Version of Android Annotations but the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2'
}
```

After that everything should work fine and the generated sources should be found. In the Android Manifest register the generated Activities like MainActivity_

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Annotation Processing in the Android Studio settings (see screen shot below)

[image: Android Studio Annotation Process Setting]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem – no generated classes created and bunch of `cannot find symbol` in result, when running compileDebugJavaWithJavac. Tried to run gradle with `--debug` but I was unable to find any error/warning from AndroidAnnotations.
In my case this was caused by double definition of class field. Ex.:

```
@Bean
MyBean bean;
…
@Bean
MyBean bean;
```

Happened to me after branch merging.